# Point subdomain from aws to azure. Possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm don't know exactly how to explain what I'm trying to do, since I'm a programmer and not a DevOps, or someone that works with infrastructure.

I have two microservices that are rest -

1 - Colors service

The colors service works with API Gateway and runs on lambdas. I'm using the Serverless framework and I use Golang. I have 3 functions:

```
create-colors - domain colors.main-domain.com/ (POST)
show-colors   - domain colors.main.domain.com/{id} (GET)
show-all-colors   - domain colors.main.domain.com/ (GET)
```

This was easy to configure. My domain is registered in GoDaddy, and I'm pointing to Route53, and I use the custom domain names to register the subdomain `colors`.

2 - Todos service

The todos service works on Azure Functions, and currently I'm using the domain that they provide (it's not custom). I have just one function there:

```
my-azure-app.com/my-azure-function (POST)
```

But I don't use a custom domain, as I'm using with AWS. Is that possible? In some way? I would like to have the domain `todos.main-domain.com/`. Just like I'm using on AWS.

Some observations:

- I'm using C#, so I can't migrate this azure function to AWS (.NET, not .NET Core)
- I can't use a AWS Lambda to call my Azure function, because the payload can me more than API Gateway accepts, and Azure is more flexible with that.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done. What you want to do is point a CNAME record from Godaddy to your Azure Function. You'll then have to tell your Azure Function to accept traffic from todos.main-domain.com.

Steps:

1. Log into Godaddy to set up the CNAME. The instructions are [here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236). If your function URI is todo-function.azurewebsites.net, you'll need to set your CNAME up so that todos.main-domain.com points to todo-function.azurewebsites.net.
2. Log into the Azure Portal. Navigate to your Azure Function's management blade. Choose the "Platform Features" tab, then "Custom Domains". You'll add a hsotname, enter in your todos.main-domain.com, validate, then add the CNAME from the dropdown below.